# Is there a way to try all feature subsets using neural networks (caret)?

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret, feature-selection

I'm working with caret and the method avNNET. I would like to try all subsets of variables while doing cross validation. So I can determine the best predictors and parameters (like a brute-force approach).

I have used stepAIC with glm, is there something similar?

Comment: There is an example of feature selection in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529537/example-for-svm-feature-selection-in-r If you change method = "svmRadial" to method = "avNNet", the script does what you need?

Answer (score 0):

In the [caret manual](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html) you will find the "pcaNNet" method, which is Neural Networks with Feature Extraction.

An example using it:

```
# define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats = 10, classProbs = TRUE)

# train the model
model <- train(Status~., data=My_data, trControl=train_control, method="pcaNNet", metric = "Kappa")

# summarize results
print(model)

# Confusion matrix
model %>% confusionMatrix()
```